# Transfer file from android(nexus1) to other server using GPRS

Tags: android, file, transfer, gprs

I want to write the application which will transfer file from android (nexus1) to some other server by using GPRS.which protocol should i use and how to implement that?

Answer (score 2):

HTTP. It's the most reliable protocol on a mobile device. There are plenty of libraries (including built into Android) that will aid you in that, and I'm sure you can [find some good tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=upload+file+android) on the net.